# c# Array.IndexOf(Array,item) need the closest item if there is no match

Tags: c#, arrays, performance, indexof, coding-efficiency

Here is method receive tow arrays as parameters , 
scores arrays(in descending order.)  which contain duplicated values , I deleted the duplicate and 
stored it in a new array without duplicate,
second array contain special player scores.

I need to evaluate her rank in the scores array for 
each score in her array.
I could do it with for loop, but it's require long time , I try to use an Array .IndexOf method but I got -1 for non existing values.

Code:

```
static int[] climbingLeaderboard(int[] scores, int[] alice)
{
    var aliceRecord = new List<int>();
    int[] oneArray;
    oneArray = scores.Distinct().ToArray();
    foreach (var aliceScore in alice)
    {
        if (aliceScore < oneArray[oneArray.Length - 1])
        {
            aliceRecord.Add(oneArray.Length + 1);
        }
        else
        {
            var rank = Array.IndexOf(oneArray, aliceScore);
            if (rank < 0)
            {
              //Here I need the help
              //I comented the un efficient code
               //for (int i = 0; i < oneArray.Length; i++)
               //{
               //    if (aliceScore >= oneArray[i])
               //    {
               //        aliceRecord.Add(i + 1);
               //        break;
               //    }
               //
               //
               //}
            }
            else
            {
                aliceRecord.Add(rank + 1);
            }
        }
    }
    return aliceRecord.ToArray();

}
```

Comment: And `alice` array is not sorted?

Comment: No it's not , and for the problem (question) purpose i cant sort it , because i need the history of her record based on her scores

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I could do it with for loop, but it requires long time

`Array.IndexOf` is an O(n) operation, so you wouldn't get much improvement in comparison to running a loop.

Sorting `oneArray` would open a faster approach - using binary search:

```
var oneArray = scores.Distinct().OrderBy(s=>s).ToArray();
foreach (var aliceScore in alice) {
    int pos = Array.BinarySearch(oneArray, aliceScore);
    if (pos < 0) {
        // When the index is negative, it represents the bitwise
        // complement of the next larger score:
        pos = ~pos - 1;
    }
    // Array is ordered in ascending order, so you want the index
    // counting from the back
    aliceRecord.Add(oneArray.Length - pos);
}
```

Comment: Sorry , Not working ,
with this sample input 
oneArray{100 , 50 , 40 , 20 , 10}
AliceScores{5 , 25 , 50 , 120}
your code output
6 , 0 , 5 , 5
My code output
6 , 4 , 2 , 1

Comment: sorry i was just editing the comment  , here is the problem link and explinatnion from hackerrank if you would to look at it https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/climbing-the-leaderboard/problem

Comment: @Mohamed That's because the array is ordered in ascending order for binary search, so you want to push `oneArray.Length - pos`. See the edit, it passes all tests on hackerrank.

Comment: OMG , you are a genius , it's took me 6 hours to write inefficient solution , even my Teacher in My c# course Run Away and told me , we may have more time tomorrow .
can you suggest some study way to improve my knowledge , i'am watching plural-sight courses but it's not giving that improvement , thanks for your time

Comment: @Mohamed I can't suggest a good site for learning this - I learned from a hopelessly outdated book some 30+ years ago, and then programming for 30+ years. One way you could improve your coding is doing a lot of hackerrank.com and topcoder.com problems, they cover a lot of programming tricks.